# Extract string/characters before a number using regex

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract everything that comes before a number using regex.

The dataframe below shows an example of what I want to do.

I want to extract everything that comes before the first number in the  `product_name` column. The `output` column is what I want to get.

Thank you in advance!

```
product_name = ['Cashew Alm Classic 6/200g', 'Cashew Buttery Sprd 8/227g', 'Chives&Garlic 6/98g']
output = ['Cashew Alm Classic', 'Cashew Butter Sprd', 'Chives&Garlic']

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(product_name, output)), columns=['product_name', 'output'])

data
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['output2']=df['product_name'].str.extract(r'(.*?)\s(?=\d)')
df

#(.*?) : non-greedy capture everything
# \s: prior to space
# (?=\d) prior to a digit - positive lookahead
```

```
    product_name                output              output2
0   Cashew Alm Classic 6/200g   Cashew Alm Classic  Cashew Alm Classic
1   Cashew Buttery Sprd 8/227g  Cashew Butter Sprd  Cashew Buttery Sprd
2   Chives&Garlic 6/98g         Chives&Garlic       Chives&Garlic
```

Answer (score 2):

I might use an `str.replace` approach here:

```py
df["output"] = df["product_name"].str.replace(r'\s+\d+/\d+\w*g$', '', regex=True)
```

This has a slight advantage over using `str.extract` in that it doesn't require us assuming what content we want to keep.  Rather it just specifies to remove any possible units term appearing at the end of the product name.

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fa1Akn/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data["output_new"] = data["product_name"].str.extract(r"^(\D+)\s+")
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
                 product_name              output           output_new
0   Cashew Alm Classic 6/200g  Cashew Alm Classic   Cashew Alm Classic
1  Cashew Buttery Sprd 8/227g  Cashew Butter Sprd  Cashew Buttery Sprd
2         Chives&Garlic 6/98g       Chives&Garlic        Chives&Garlic
```